# Dualizing map of Abelian Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know for abelian variety $X $and line bundle $L,$ we have dualizing homomorphism $\phi_L $ for X to its Picard group:
$$x \rightarrow [t_x^* L \otimes L^{-1}],$$
where $t_x$ is the left translation by $x$.
Now for sufficient good $X$, $L$ is from a Weil divisor $D,$that is, $L=\mathcal{O}(D).$
We have $t_x^* \mathcal{O}(D)= \mathcal{O}(D-x)$(By Moonen’s book, for example)（$D-x$ is the translation of $D$ by $-x$)and let $X$ be an elliptic curve then $x$ is divisor, put this into  $[t_x^* L \otimes L^{-1}]$ it’s obviously not reasonable.

Where is the problem?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(D-x)$ doesn't make sense, since $x$ is not necessarily a divisor on $X$. Also your question is not very clear?

Comment: @EvansGambit Thanks, I’ve restricted to the curve case

Comment: Still not clear to me: if you put $L=\mathcal{O}(D)$ and you calculate $\phi_L(x)$, then what is the question? Is your question: 'Is it true that $t_x^*(\mathcal{O}(D))=\mathcal{O}(D-x)$?'

Comment: @EvansGambit When I put L=O(D), \phi_L(x)=O(-x), but it should be O(D-x) or something else concerning D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are confused about the relation between the addition of divisors and the addition law on an abelian variety.
Let me explain the case of an elliptic curve in detail.

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $O\in E$ be its unit.
We write $\star\colon E\times E\to E$ for the group law on $E$ and $({-})^{-1}\colon E\to E$ for the morphism taking inverse.
Recall (from, for example, 2.6 of Hartshorne's book) that for any two closed points $P,Q\in E$ we have
$$
\tag{1}[P]+[Q]\equiv[P\star Q]+[O]
$$
where $\equiv$ denotes the linear equivlence of divisors.

Now consider a line bundle $L$ on $E$.
We can write $L\simeq\mathcal{O}(m_1[P_1]+\cdots+m_n[P_n])$ for some closed points $P_1,\dots,P_n\in E$ and $m_1,\dots,m_n\in \mathbb{Z}$.
For any closed point $Q\in E$ we have
$$
t_Q^*L\simeq \mathcal{O}(m_1[P_1\star Q^{-1}]+\dots+m_n[P_n\star Q^{-1}])
$$
and hence
$$
t_Q^*L\otimes L^{-1}\simeq \mathcal{O}(m_1[P_1\star Q^{-1}]+\dots+m_n[P_n\star Q^{-1}]-m_1[P_1]-\dots-m_n[P_n]).
$$
We see from (1) that $[P_i\star Q^{-1}]-[P_i]$ is linearly equivalent to $[Q^{-1}]-[O]$, so we get
$$
t_Q^*L\otimes L^{-1}\simeq \mathcal{O}((m_1+\dots+m_n)([Q^{-1}]-[O])).
$$
You can also check (again using (1)) that $Q\mapsto t_Q^*L\otimes L^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

**Claim:** $t_x^*(\mathcal{O}_X(D)=\mathcal{O}_X(t_{-x}(D)).$

To see this, let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. Then  $$t_x^*(\mathcal{O}_X(D)(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(D)(t_x(U))=\{f\in \mathcal{K}_X(t_x(U)) ~| ~div(f)+D|_{t_x(U)}\geq 0\}.$$

On the other hand,
$$\mathcal{O}_X(t_{-x}(D))(U)=\{g\in \mathcal{K}_X(U) ~| ~div(g)+t_{-x}(D)|_{U}\geq 0\}.$$

Consider the map $t_x: U\to t_x(U)$ as a morphism of varieties, then $$t_{-x}(D)|_{U}=t_{-x}(\sum n_ip_i)|_{U}=[\sum_in_i(p_i-x)]|_{U}=[\sum_in_ip_i]|_{t_x(U)}=D|_{t_x(U)}$$
simply because $p_i-x\in U$ iff $p_i\in t_x(U)$.

Consider the map $$t_x^*(\mathcal{O}_X(D)(U)\to \mathcal{O}_X(t_{-x}(D))(U)$$
sending $$f\mapsto t_x^*(f).$$

Now simply observe that $div(t_x^*(f))=[div(f)]|_{t_x(U)}$

viewing $div(f)$ and $div(t_x^*(f))$ as divisors on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the proof, but I still wonder the explicit form of the dualizing map in the curve case.